# Mapbox GL JS get features within geoson boundary

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Below is a complete minimal example of a dot layer on top of a choropleth layer. You simply need to add an access token and it will work. When a user clicks within one of the choropleth boundaries I would like to get a list of the points within that boundary. This is so that I can use this data to populate an element elsewhere on the page. I am aware that some boundaries overlap, but I am not worried about how this is handled.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link
    href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken =
      "your token here";

    const geojson_url =
      "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/d4d519d1d1a1455a9b82331228f77489_4.geojson";

    fetch(geojson_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(geojson => {
        const data = [
          { lat: "52.04009", long: "-0.52926" },
          { lat: "51.45906", long: "-2.60329" },
          { lat: "51.24257", long: "-0.58795" },
          { lat: "51.51161", long: "-0.11625" },
          { lat: "51.38113", long: "-2.36011" },
          { lat: "51.449824", long: "-2.60034" },
          { lat: "52.04009", long: "-0.52926" },
          { lat: "51.06386", long: "-2.90667" },
          { lat: "50.72623", long: "-3.5222" }
        ];

        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: "map",
          style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
          zoom: 5.5,
          center: [-2.2, 53]
        });

        map.on("load", function() {
          // choropleth
          geojson.features = geojson.features.map(feature => {
            feature["id"] = feature.properties.objectid;
            return feature;
          });
          map.addSource("leps", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: geojson
          });
          map.addLayer({
            id: "leps-fills",
            type: "fill",
            source: "leps",
            paint: {
              "fill-color": "green",
              "fill-opacity": 0.5
            }
          });

          map.on("click", "leps-fills", function(e) {
            // using this event, I would like to find all the points within the clicked boundary
            console.log("list of points here");
          });

          // point data layers
          // create points geojson data
          const pointMapGeojson = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: data.map((g, i) => {
              return {
                type: "Feature",
                properties: g,
                id: i,
                geometry: {
                  type: "Point",
                  coordinates: [g.long, g.lat]
                }
              };
            })
          };

          map.addSource("point_layer", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: pointMapGeojson
          });
          map.addLayer({
            id: "point_layer",
            type: "circle",
            source: "point_layer",
            layout: {
              visibility: "visible"
            }
          });
        });
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/). It provides a function to find any points within the polygon. https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon

Here is the example:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGFybmRlcHUiLCJhIjoiY2l6dXZ5OXVkMDByZDMycXI2NGgyOGdyNiJ9.jyTchGQ8N1gjPdra98qRYg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-46.6062, -23.5513],
  zoom: 11
});

map.on('load', function () {

  var points = turf.points([
      [-46.6318, -23.5523],
      [-46.6246, -23.5325],
      [-46.6062, -23.5513],
      [-46.663, -23.554],
      [-46.643, -23.557]
  ]);
  
  var searchWithin = turf.polygon([[
      [-46.653,-23.543],
      [-46.634,-23.5346],
      [-46.613,-23.543],
      [-46.614,-23.559],
      [-46.631,-23.567],
      [-46.653,-23.560],
      [-46.653,-23.543]
  ]]);
  
  // Find point within polygon
  var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, searchWithin);
  
  // Draw polygon
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'searchWithin',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': searchWithin
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#525252',
      'fill-opacity': 0.5
    }
  });
  // Draw all points
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'points',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': points
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': 5,
      'circle-color': 'red',
      'circle-opacity': 1
    }
  });
  // Draw points within polygon feature
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'ptsWithin',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': ptsWithin
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': 5,
      'circle-color': 'blue',
      'circle-opacity': 1
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; };
```

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```